# Get the intersection of two arrays with different structure

Tags: php

I'm having two arrays and try to get the user_id exists in both , but I cant use array intersect function , I wasn't able to do it unless i used loop inside loop and I guess that is so bad because arrays will be too big , Is there any solution? or way to make array intersect work ..

[image: [1]:] https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rlZF.jpg

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to extract the user_id's that appear on both arrays, the easiest way to accomplish this (without loops) is by combining the array_column and array_intersect functions:

```php
$user_ids = array_intersect(
    array_column($arr1, 'user_id'),
    array_column($arr2, 'user_id')
);
```

You can test this out on this [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/A0mDMp).